# Defining my own key

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I saw the so called `<Leader>` in my `vimrc` quite often. But is there a way to define my own key in a similar manner? I mean I would like to define some sort of `<Mykey>` and use it further in my `vimrc` to define more complicated combinations. I mean something like this:

```
nnoremap <Mykey>u "some keystroke
```

This means that depending on how I define `<Mykey>` I get different combinations with it.

Comment: I think what you want is described at `:h <plug>`

Answer (score 6):

You can define your own `<leader>` key with:

```
let mapleader = "something"
```

You could also hack the `<localleader>` to get a second `<leader>`:

```
let localleader = "something else"
```

But `<leader>` and `<localleader>` are not special keys *at all*. Assuming your `<leader>` is set to `,` (the example in `:help mapleader`) the two mappings below are *strictly* equivalent:

```
nnoremap <leader>f :find *
nnoremap ,f        :find *
```

So, basically, you can use any normal key to *function* as `<leader>` without setting anything.

Answer (score 3):

Vim has this abstraction, and it's `<Leader>` (and the `<LocalLeader>` variant which is meant for buffer-local mappings). Unfortunately, there's only one.

If you need a common prefix for a set of custom mappings, and you want to be able to change this in a single location, you can define a variable, and then use `:execute` to define the mappings.

#### Example

```
let g:MyKey = '<Leader>x'
execute 'nnoremap' g:MyKey . 'u' "some keystroke
execute 'nnoremap' g:MyKey . 'v' "another keystroke
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting usage that I first saw (and wandered about) in [Shougo's Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/blob/master/doc/unite.txt#L211) plugin, which creates an artificial leader key "placeholder" (I'm quoting directly from the Unite's help file):

```
" The prefix key.
nnoremap    [unite]   <Nop>
nmap        f         [unite]

nnoremap <silent> [unite]c  :<C-u>UniteWithCurrentDir
        \ -buffer-name=files buffer bookmark file<CR>

... (etc.)
```

In the above example, the whole sequence of characters `[unite]` is mapped non-recursively in normal mode to do nothing (and thus, it becomes a "prefix"!) Then, a "leader" key is assigned to this complicated `<Nop>`; in this case, `f`.

What follows are the actual maps, in which every time you type `f` `<some other char(s)>`, Vim translates it to `[unite]` `<some other char(s)>` -- if the combination is defined (and typed in time), the map gets executed, otherwise -- the prefix is cancelled (because it gets resolved by itself to `<Nop>`, i.e. nothing) and it's like you didn't type it at all. Mind boggling.

I didn't test, but I think the way the sequence itself is defined (here, `[unite]`) is quite relevant -- if I got it right, it will create delays for any key combinations starting with `[`, `[u`, `[un` and so on. So you would always want to use a leader placeholder "string" that starts with characters you don't *normally* (pun) use by themselves.